# How to submit two forms in jsf with Ajax or without Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, submit

I have basically two problems.

When I press the button in Form1, it is working fine, but I can't see the messages from FacesContext.
Another problem is in Form2. When I press the button only once, it goes to the server but nothing happens, no submit. But when I press it on second time, it is working fine. There is of course the same problem like in form one, that I can't see the messages from FacesContext. Could you please help and tell me what is causing that or is there another solution for having multiple forms inside one page?

```
                    <p:tabView>
                        <p:tab title="Form1">
                            <h:form id="form1">
                                <p:inputText id="txtInput" value="#{controller.selected.defaultLayout}" />
                                <h:commandButton value="Submit other form" action="#{controller.createMenu()}">
                                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                                </h:commandButton>

                            </h:form>
                        </p:tab>
                        <p:tab title="Form2">
                            <h:form id="form2">
                                <p:inputText id="txtInput2" value="#{controller.selected.defaultTheme}" />
                                <h:commandButton value="Submit other form" action="#{controller.createMenu2()}">
                                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                                </h:commandButton>
                             </h:form>
                        </p:tab>
                    </p:tabView>
```

Controller:

```
public String createMenu() {

        Menu menu = current.getMenuMenuId();


        try {
            //current.getMenuMenuId().setMenuCreated(true);
            //getFacade().edit(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/Bundle").getString("MenuCreated"));-----> never visible!

            return "";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }

    }
```

EDIT: I took the outer -tags off and then the page is not working anymore, then I get the error message:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':form2' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt77
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.getResolvedId(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:285)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.appendIds(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:272)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.buildAjaxCommand(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.getScript(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:86)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorBase.getScript(ClientBehaviorBase.java:103)
```

Thank you!
Sami

Answer (score 1):

Nesting forms is not valid html. This will cause unexpected behavior. Remove the outer form and see which of your issues persist.

UPDATE:

Primefaces tabview works without form as well. However if you have input elements and command buttons inside your tabs you need a form. But this is a html requirement and not PF specific. You should remove the outer form only and not the inner forms. Please update your question with your current version.

Comment: Primefaces requires that tabs should be surrounded by form. I however tried to take form off and I got this: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':form2' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt78. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: I took the outer form-tags off, no success :)

Comment: Check the source code of your page in browser. What is the ID of both of your forms?

Comment: The form in the tab is prefixed with the tabView-id (something like: j_idXY:form2). Try to use the full id in your render and execute attributes.